# WooCommerce API update order status

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

When trying to update the order with

```
$client->orders->update_status($order_id_to_update, $status);
```

it creates a new order with the exact same information and updates status for both the original and the newly created order. 
How can I stop this from happening and only have my submitted order_ID changing status?

Answer (score 1):

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$order->update_status('pending');
```

Try this code snippet

Comment: hi can you tell me what's the value for "authentication required" ? i mean the status code for it?

Comment: @fahadsaleem Please add a new question with details that you tried. you can see the API docs [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication-over-http)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have give a coherent order_id_to_update and well status !
If you put a int value on $status, you'll have a order who have a know status, so it will not visible in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

With Python it's as simple as `print(wcapi.put("orders/727", data).json())`, where data is a key-value pair object.

See: http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#orders